# How can I calculate the number of added/deleted/modified files between two commits in Git?

Tags: git

Is there a way to calculate the number of **files** that were added/deleted/changed (each one separately) between two commits in git?

```
git --no-pager diff <commit-ish1>..<commit-ish2> --stat
```

only gives files changed, not specifying how many were added or deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like;

```
git diff --name-status master | cut -c 1 | sort | uniq -c
     32 A
     16 D
    611 M
     60 R
```

See the docs for --diff-filter to see what the codes mean; https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203.